# Does the WebStorm Javascript IDE (or any IDE) understand SMD (Service Mapping Description) files

Tags: javascript, ide, dojo, webstorm

We are looking into tools for Javascript development and plan to use Dojo with SMD files to interface to our JSONRPC backend  API - it seems like a natural feature of an IDE that it would understand the format of SMD files and be able to validate your function calls against those defined in the SMD file.  Does anyone know if WebStorm (or some other IDE) actually has such a feature?

Comment: I don't see [any mention on their features page](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/index.html). They do offer a 30 day free trial, so you could try it out and kick the tires, see if it is a feature they don't advertise.

Comment: I've added a feature request to JetBrains issue tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11368 (star/vote to get notified when it's implemented).